# Ошибка: client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x0000000004CC4A60> Unclosed connector connections:

Tags: python, aiogram, asyncio, aiohttp

**Ошибка:** client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x0000000004CC4A60>
Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x0000000004C9BCA0>, 20902.839)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x0000000004CC4520>

Использую **aiogram** для проверки **подписки** пользователя на бота.

```
bot = Bot(token)
await bot.me
await bot.send_chat_action(user_id,'choose_sticker')
```

Код исправно **работает**, но выходит это "предупреждение".

Из-за чего это сообщение может появляться. И как его можно скрыть? (любыми методами)

Comment: Требуем больше кода!

Comment: Условно так. Где токены это токены, а users список id людей.

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import asyncio

bot = Bot(token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

def check_referrals():
 while True:
  pass

@dp.message_handler()
async def message_handler(message: types.Message):
 for user_id in users:
  bot = Bot(token2)
  await bot.me
  await bot.send_chat_action(user_id,'choose_sticker')  # где-то тут ошибка возникает

if __name__ == '__main__':
 loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
 loop.create_task(check_referrals())
 executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)

Comment: Бот очень большой и со множеством функций, так что даже пореза элементы, которые не будут участвовать код будет большим.
Здесь я описал основные вещи, которые влияют.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы я не нашёл, но похоже это происходит, если создать два экземляра бота.

Я просто сделал данную операцию с помощью синхронной библиотеки **telebot**, хоть это и медленней:

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
bot.get_me()
bot.send_chat_action(user_id,'choose_sticker')
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
# ... ваш код
s = await bot.get_session()
await s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сделать так

```
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, loop=loop)
```